# how to make code wait for function return in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, socket.io, async-await

I understand node js is async and i've looked many resources to fix this with no success. my problem is, i have this mongodb query i'm executing, but my function returns before the query finishes i know about promises and i'm using them but it doesn't seem to work, what am i doing wrong. my code can be found below:

```js
function findConversation(Id){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    ConversationSchema.find({ 'participants.Id': Id }, function (err, conversations) {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      if (conversations) {
        console.log("Conversation JSON: " + conversations)
      }
      resolve(conversations)
    })
 })
}
```

this is the query that i'm executing, but it's called in the bellow function:

```js
function getConversations(user){
 var newConversations = []

 query.findConversation(user.userName).then(function(convers) {
  if(convers) {
   console.log("conversation was found: " + convers)
   newConversations = convers
  }
  else {
   console.log("conversation was not found: " + convers)
  }
 }).catch(function(reason) {
  console.log("failure when finding conversation: " + reason)
 })
 return newConversations
}
```

now the above function is the one that returns without waiting for the promise, bellow i call this function:

```js
socket.on(VERIFY_USER, (nickname, callback)=>{

    query.userExist(nickname).then(function(user){
      if(user){
        console.log("user exist")

        var conversation  = factories.getConversations(user)
        console.log("Existing user Conversations: " + conversation)
        callback({ userExist:true, user:factories.getUser(user, socket.id), conversations: conversation})
      }
      else {
        console.log("user does not exist")
        callback({ userExist:false, user:factories.createUser(nickname, socket.id), conversations:[]})
      }
    }).catch(function(reason) {
         console.error(reason);
    })
 })
```

this always returns
Existing user Conversations:

Comment: yes, I have also been fighting with the same issue... because promise does not wait query's return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that when using promises you have to use them throughout your code. Anything that requires an asynchronous function in order to return correctly also has to be asynchronous. I think you do understand that `query` doesn't complete before `getConversations` does, and that `getConversations` *will not wait* for query to complete.

So here `getConversations` has to be structured just like `findConversation` with a new Promise and calling `resolve(newConversations)`. You would then use `.then` just as you did before when you call it.

```
factories.getConversations(user).then((conversation) => {
    console.log("Existing user Conversations: " + conversation);
    callback({userExist: true, user: factories.getUser(user, socket.id), conversations: conversation});
});
```

If you find using promises too difficult or messy and you are able to use ES6 you should probably use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). This will allow you to write code as if it were synchronous yet still being non-blocking in reality. If getConversations were an asynchronous function, for example, you would then be able to use it very simply:

```
let conversation = await factories.getConversations(user);
console.log("Existing user Conversations: " + conversation);
callback({userExist: true, user: factories.getUser(user, socket.id), conversations: conversation});
```

Overall you should review how promises work or really try to learn how async/await works.

Edit: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)